# Problemas com expressões regulares (url amigável)

Tags: regex, htaccess, url

Eu estou tendo problemas na hora de ler o código de um determinado produto de uma URL amigável.

Com a expressão regular que eu coloquei, ele está aceitando todos os caracteres que estão a frente do código do produto, ou seja, escrevendo `produto/9789/quantidade/5` ele entende o código do produto como `9789/quantidade/5`, e não só o `9789`.

Alguém poderia me ajudar a colocar essa expressão regular corretamente?

Aqui está a que eu usei:

```
RewriteRule ^carrinho\/produto\/(.+)?$ carrinho.php?produto=$1&quantidade=1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^carrinho\/produto\/(.+)\/quantidade\/([0-9]+)\/?$ carrinho.php?produto=$1&quantidade=$2 [NC,L]
```

Outro problema é que quando o usuário coloca uma `/` no final do código do produto na primeira URL ela vai junto para o código do produto.

Comment: Ao invés de `\/produto\/(.+)\/` coloque `\/produto\/([0-9]+)\/`, tal qual fez para a `quantidade`.

Answer (score 2):

```
^carrinho\/produto\/(.+)?$
```

Significa capturar `carrinho/produto/` seguido opcionalmente de *qualquer coisa* até o fim da linha. O problema é esse *qualquer coisa*. Pela regra, pode perfeitamente ser `9789/quantidade/5`.

Reescreva limitando a ser apenas números. Assim:

```
^carrinho\/produto\/(\d+)?$
```

Ou se preferir:

```
^carrinho\/produto\/([0-9]+)?$
```

Comment: O problema é que o produto não necessariamente terá só números, ele pode ser composto por letras e caracteres especiais... Como eu devo fazer a máscara para esse caso?

Answer (score 2):

A primeira expressão pode ser ajustada para não capturar `/` no produto:

```
^carrinho\/produto\/([^\/]+)?$
```

Assim ela não vai bater com as URLs longas que tem quantidade, deixando-as para a segunda expressão, que parece estar funcionando bem.

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se lhe é útil, mas aqui esta uma expressão para buscar apenas os parâmetros passados da url, não fiz testes com varias urls apenas a que você passou.

#### Regex

`(\w+=([^&]*))`

#### Explicação

```
\w+= = alnum - letras a números - 1 ou mais - seguido de =
[^&]* = tudo exito & - se quiser limitar para `alnum` substiruir por [\w]*, - 0 ou mais
```

#### Alterações

Esta Regex ira lhe retornar um array como pode ver [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/zG6xI1/1).

```
Caso queira um array simples de `tipo=dado` elimine o parenteses interno (\w+=[^&]*)
Caso queira um array de `dados` elimine o parenteses externo \w+=([^&]*)
```